# Image click opens lightbox for album of specific images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create a lightbox album.

Currently, all that I can find on the internet is a lightbox that has an album of the current image set. What I am looking to accomplish is to have a separate album for each image that is clicked.

For example, if I click lightbox image 1, it opens up an album of images specifically defined for that image. Same for 2 and 3 as well.

Image of example:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which library are you using? But of course this is possible. You have to group your images like different classes or different rel.

Comment: I've looked at the W3Schools lightbox and I liked it. However, I can't seem to figure out how I'm going to change it to what I want.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think in your case the best solution would be to have all the albums hidden in the page, and when you click on an image you just show the corresponding album. This is a really simple example of what I mean:

```js
var showAlbum = function(id) {
 $('#' + id).addClass('visible');
}

$('.album-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  showAlbum($(this).attr('data-target'));
});

var closeAlbum = function($elem) {
 $elem.parent().removeClass('visible');
}


$('.close').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  closeAlbum($(this));
})
```

```css
.album {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: none;
}

.album.visible {
  display: block;
}

.album h2 {
  color: white;
}

.album img {
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="album-trigger" href="#" data-target="album-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="#"></a>
<a class="album-trigger" href="#" data-target="album-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="#"></a>

<div class="album" id="album-1">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <h2>Album1</h2>
  <ul class="album-images">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="album" id="album-2">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <h2>Album2</h2>
  <ul class="album-images">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```